# Android - Duplicate class found in modules protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google speech github android project. After upgrading all the files versions finally it managed to get down to a single issue now and I could not solve it.
Here error the message:

```
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.8.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
```

Theres hundreds more lines with similar warning.

To solve this I tried many other versions of "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.21.0" and "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.8.0" by changing their numbers but nothing matched those methods and I keep getting that error message.

The strange fact is: upgrading "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite: ---" of 3.0.1 gives this error: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:3.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app`
 but keeping it to the version of 1.21.0 doesn't give any error but will show that duplicate error message that clearly has the version of 3.0.1 that is supposed to be not present.

Heres the dependencies list in my gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// Support libraries
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

// gRPC
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:3.0.1"

implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.8.0'

// OAuth2 for Google API
implementation('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.16.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}

// Tests
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

How can I solve this duplication error message?

Comment: Why are you using the lite and full version of protobuf? Choose only one and remove the other.

Comment: Hey thanks. It was all in that project. Both the versions. And removing lite version broke the project. Removing the non lite version solved it.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it fixed

Comment: after adding a translation client dependency this duplciate class error message reappeared.

Comment: What dependency is it?

Comment: //Translation
  implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.79.0'

Comment: Error is: `Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.7.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.7.1) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-java-3.7.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.7.1) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)` ____and a bunch of similar lines.

Comment: It's because protobuf is already added in google cloud translate. Have a look at the pom.xml - https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-translate/pom.xml

Comment: Try removing protobuf all together. You can't have 2 of the same classes, that's why you're getting this error

Comment: Removing protobuf lite (which is only available) will fail the project like I said earlier. I tested after removing it altogether and it failed showing more errors, so It cant be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes deleting the duplicated R.java and BuildConfig files may resolve the issue but if it doesn't help me because it was always recreating it and showing the above error.

I had the same issue What helped me is understanding why the files were duplicated at the first places. But I realise it was because I mistakenly made a loop dependency between my modules in the project. 
By doing this when compiler started creating class for one of the modules it already compiled as a dependency it showed the error. 
So Removing the unneeded dependency and recompiling the project fixed the problem.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing with dependency methods with resources. 
Whats unneeded in this project that can be removed? 
I dont think R.java has to do anything with this error. Its not about resources.